# MSSQL ORDER BY Passed List

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Lucene to perform queries on a subset of SQL data which returns me a scored list of RecordIDs, e.g. 11,4,5,25,30 .

I want to use this list to retrieve a set of results from the full SQL Table by RecordIDs.

So `SELECT * FROM MyFullRecord
  where RecordID in (11,5,3,25,30)`

I would like the retrieved list to maintain the scored order.

I can do it by using an Order by like so;

`ORDER BY (CASE WHEN RecordID = 11 THEN 0
           WHEN RecordID = 5 THEN 1
               WHEN RecordID = 3 THEN 2
               WHEN RecordID = 25 THEN 3
               WHEN RecordID = 30 THEN 4
           END)`

I am concerned with the loading of the server loading especially if I am passing long lists of RecordIDs.  Does anyone have experience of this or how can I determine an optimum list length.

Are there any other ways to achieve this functionality in MSSQL?

Roger

Comment: Usually - this would be faster to resort in the application layer which handles the Lucene search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can record your list into a table or table variable with sorting priorities.
And then join your table with this sorting one.

```
DECLARE TABLE @tSortOrder (RecordID INT, SortOrder INT)
INSERT INTO @tSortOrder (RecordID, SortOrder)
SELECT 11, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 25, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 5

SELECT *
FROM yourTable T
LEFT JOIN @tSortOrder S ON T.RecordID = S.RecordID
ORDER BY S.SortOrder
```

Comment: Yes, and @tSortOrder could be a table-valued parameter. Very good solution.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I used a variation on this, creating the "sortorder" table from my C# code and then using the left join from a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a searched order by statement, you could create an in memory table to join. It's easier on the eyes and definitely scales better.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  mfr.*
FROM    MyFullRecord mfr
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT * 
          FROM (VALUES (1, 11),
                       (2, 5),
                       (3, 3),
                       (4, 25),
                       (5, 30)
               ) q(ID, RecordID)
        ) q ON q.RecordID = mfr.RecordID
ORDER BY
        q.ID
```

Look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75b68/2) for a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyFullRecord where RecordID in (11,5,3,25,30)

ORDER BY 
    CHARINDEX(','+CAST(RecordID AS varchar)+',',
              ','+'11,5,3,25,30'+',')
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/294ac/3)</kbd>

Comment: I don't see how this improves things.